# In App Purchase Localization

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I have added Japanese to the available languages for the in-app purchase product on iTunes Connect.  I have set my phone to Japanese, however, when I run the following code it still results in English text:

`NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);`

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Is your app also localized to Japanese?

Answer (score 2):

I think that SKProduct get the localized info according to the iTunes Store account with which you are logged in.

You need to create a Test User for the Japanese iTunes Store instead of the US iTunes Store (**iTunes Connect -> Manage Users**).

Then login as that user (**Settings -> iTunes & App Stores**) and reload your SKProducts.

That worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

Are you running your test device in Japanese?

Go to General -> International -> Language and choose Japanese from there and try again.
You don't have to localize your app to get this feature.

Comment: As I mentioned above. My phone is set to Japanese language.